# What are the right reverse PTR, domain keys, and SPF settings for two domains running the same application?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, reverse-dns, domainkeys

I just read [Jeff Atwood](https://serverfault.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)'s [recent post on DNS configuration for email](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) and decided to give it a go on my application.

I have a web-app that runs on one server under two different IPs and domain names, on both HTTP and HTTPS for each:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.org
  ServerAlias www.foo.org
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
  ServerName foo.org
  ServerAlias www.foo.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bar.org
  ServerAlias www.bar.org
  ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 2.3.4.5:443>
  ServerName bar.org
  ServerAlias www.bar.org
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using GMail as my SMTP server.

Do I need the reverse PTR and SenderID records? If so, do I put the same ones on *all* of my records (foo.org, www.foo.org, bar.org, www.bar.org, ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM, ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM, ..)?

I'm pretty sure I want the domain-keys records, but I'm not sure which domains to attach them to. The Google mail servers? foo.org and bar.org? Everything?

**Later**

All mail that the system sends comes from an `___@foo.org` address, regardless of which domain the user uses. The domains point to the exact same code and the code doesn't care about domains as far as email is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create records for each of the “domain name” parts of the addresses you send from. So, if you send as @foo.org and @subdomain.foo.org and @bar.com, I’d create entries in all three. In the case of SPF, you can use `include:<domain>` to only specify things in one place (indeed, if you’re using GApps on a domain, you’ll want to use `include:_spf.google.com` rather than specifying Google’s servers directly (especially as the ones Google publishes and advises you to use as your MX records are the *outbound* mail servers).

Regarding the PTR records: you only need one PTR for each IP, and it should point to a FQDN which resolves back to that IP. It doesn’t have to bear much relation to anything other than this, but some particularly inbound mail servers may *prefer* that it matches the hostname used in the EHLO when you establish an ESMTP connection to them.

Comment: All mail comes from an `@foo.org` address, regardless of which domain the user uses. So that's a PTR record for 1.2.3.4, a PTR record for 2.3.4.5, a domain-key record for foo.org, and an SPF record for foo.org with includes for all the Google servers?

Comment: You’ll probably only need a PTR record for one of the two IPs if you know that outbound connections will only ever use that IP, but there’s no harm (and not very much extra work) in setting up PTRs for both. Otherwise, yes — that’s it exactly.